# Changing to a new certificate authority for existing website

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

We have a website certificate issued that will expire soon. The current certificate issuer is charging us too much and we would like to change to a new company.

If we get a new certificate from another company (which would be properly certified and all), would our users get any warnings in their browsers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they will not receive a warning, as long as the new certificate is issued with a CA root that the client trusts.

Answer (score 3):

+1 Chris.

The only additional thing to beware of is whether your new certificate provider uses chained certificates. If they do, you will need to ensure that your web server is configured to deliver the chain, when you install the new certificate.